# Adding a child element before myArray.map(x => ) causes only one child to be rendered from the array

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, map-function

Apologies for how this is worded as I don't know how to properly explain this problem.

I have the following piece of code. As it stands `myArray` has 10 elements in it.

if I have the `<LeadingChild/>` component above the `.map`, only the first of the 10 elements displays.

```js
<Slider>
    <LeadingChild/>
    {myArray.map(x => (<Card cardTitle={x.title} shortDescription={x.shortDescription} Link= {x.link}></Card>))}
</Slider>
```

Removing the `<LeadingChild/>` component like below, allows the 10 elements to display just fine.

```js
<Slider>
    {myArray.map(x => (<Card cardTitle={x.title} shortDescription={x.shortDescription} Link= {x.link}></Card>))}
</Slider>
```

No errors are thrown.

I would like the end result to have both the leading child and all elements that exist within `myArray` to be displayed

Update:
I've created a new array of ReactNode's, that I've pre-populated with all the elements in `myArray` but with the `<LeadingChild/>` in the array as well.

This has resolved the problem but feels like a dirty solution.

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain exactly why this happens, but I'm pretty sure it's because of the lack of `key` attribute in your mapped elements.

React uses key attributes for re-rendering comparisons and doesn't render elements with an existing key (elements meaning html lists' items). Some strange behaviour can occur when those list elements don't have a key attribute at all.

Try to add unique keys to your `Card` elements, like this:

```
{ myArray.map(elem => <Card key={elem.id} />) }
```

Comment: Sorry I don't quite follow. Could you maybe provide a basic example

Comment: @DamianJacobs did it help?

Comment: Your explanation was great but unfortunately no luck with that as the solution. Same results.

I came right by adding my leadingChild component to the array and changing the array to be an array of ReactNode's. Ill investigate a little further and see if I'm maybe just missing something small.

Thank you very much for your time and effort.